# Server Cookies not working in identity .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using a web API core with angular 6 
for authentication, I am using Identity with a server cookies 
everything working good but when I want to use the **[Authorize]** Attribute
with the role or not above any action, it always returns 401 as unauthorized request.

**In Startup.ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {

                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan =
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(_config["Tokens:accessFailedwaitingMin"]));
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(_config["Tokens:accessFailedCount"]);
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Override the default events
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ReplaceRedirectorWithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden),
                OnRedirectToLogin = ReplaceRedirectorWithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            };

            // Configure our application cookie
            options.Cookie.Name = ".test";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // This must be true to prevent XSS
            //options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None; // Should ideally be "Always"

            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

        });



        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

And in **Startup.Configure**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseCookiePolicy();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
```

Note: however I am using server cookies, these cookies with name '.test' have not come to the browser this image will indicate that :
[image]

Comment: Are you using Angular to log in? You can't do that with an HttpOnly cookie.

Comment: yes i am using page to login from angular to api with http call

Comment: You need to have something like JWT authentication for integration with angular,
you can even setup multiple authentication schemes on same application
here is my answer to that as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115482/jwt-bearer-token-authorization-being-applied-on-exisitng-mvc-web-appication-in/55116529#55116529

Comment: @IkramShah but before I am using the same way with angularJs and it is working successfully